# I got these types of Error when i get return from main() function during Debuging "Unable to open crtexe.c "

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to Debug this program, when i run it in Debug mode its working fine, but when it returns from the main, i mean when program execution is completed this error message Pop in VS Cclode

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int counter = 10;
    counter++;
    printf("The Counter Value is : %d\n", counter);
    printf("Hello World!!\n");    
    return 0;
}
```

[This is Local Variable Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xtpd.jpg)

[This is the error message i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfti4.jpg)

[Whole Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVyTI.jpg)

Comment: This is not a error message. Don't step out main into CRT functions.

Comment: why this is popping up? I mean reason behind it?

Comment: You are trying to step out the main function into a CRT function and you don't have CRT source files.

Comment: okay, i got you

Answer (score 1):

While Using the Ubantu Extension in vs code, for debugging your C/C++ code, Vs Code is writing or accessing files having no privileges , CRT sources files belongs so Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL), Best way to avoid such pop error is to ***put a break point*** while returning from the main function